# Python - LOGIC ERROR - on racquetball simulation

Tags: python, logic, simulation

I just started to learn python(self-taught) and I'm trying to do a simulation of racquetball game. 
I can run the simulation with: a==15 or b==15, but when I add the extra condition: abs(a-b)>=2 IT GOES CRAZY(the simOneGame turns to an infinite loop). Here is what I tried so far:

```
return a == 15 or b == 15 ------> this one works perfectly

return a == 15 or b == 15 and abs(a-b) >= 2 --> this doesn't freeze but the logic is wrong(I think)

return (a == 15 or b == 15) and abs(a-b) >= 2 --> freezing

return (a == 15 or b == 15) and (abs(a-b) >= 2) --> freezing

return ((a == 15 or b == 15) and (abs(a-b) >= 2)) --> freezing
```

Thanks a lot and sorry if this seems too long(maybe I should've typed just the function gameOver()?...)

Here is my code so far:

```
from random import random

def main():

    printIntro()
    n, probA, probB = getInputs()
    winsA, winsB = simNGames(n, probA, probB)
    displayResults(winsA, winsB)
def printIntro():

    print("\nVOLLEYBALL SIMULATION\n")
    print("The inputs will be the number of simulations(n),")
    print("   the probability player A wins his serve(probA)")
    print("   and the probability player B wins his serve(probB).")
    print("The program will display how many games won player A(winsA),")
    print("   how many games won player B(winsB),")
    print("   and the percentages of winnings for both players.\n")

def getInputs():

    n = int(input("Enter the number of simulations: "))
    probA = float(input("Enter the probability player A wins his serve: "))
    probB = float(input("Enter the probability player B wins his serve: "))
    return n, probA, probB

def simNGames(n, probA, probB):

    winsA, winsB = 0, 0
    for i in range(n):
        # player A serves on odd games
        if i % 2 == 0:
            serving = "A"
        # player B serves on even games
        else:
            serving = "B"
        scoreA, scoreB = simOneGame(probA, probB, serving)
        if scoreA > scoreB:
            winsA = winsA + 1
        else:
            winsB = winsB + 1
    return winsA, winsB

def simOneGame(probA, probB, serving):

    scoreA, scoreB = 0, 0
    while not gameOver(scoreA, scoreB):
        if serving == "A":
            if random() < probA:
                scoreA = scoreA + 1
            else:
                serving = "B"
        else:
            if random() < probB:
                scoreB = scoreB + 1
            else:
                serving = "A"
    return scoreA, scoreB

def gameOver(a, b):

    # the game is over if a player gets to 15 AND the difference is at least 2.
    # this shoud work... BUT IT DOESN'T... simOneGame turns to an infinete loop with a large number of simulations...
    return (a == 15 or b == 15) and abs(a-b) >= 2  

def displayResults(winsA, winsB):

    print("Player A won {0} games({1:1.0%})".format(winsA, winsA/(winsA+winsB)))
    print("Player B won {0} games({1:0.0%})".format(winsB, winsB/(winsA+winsB)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is happening if both players get 14 points ? Maybe you should rather check that their scores are greater or equal to 15.

Comment: What if one player has 17 points and the other has 14? What do you think your code would do?

Comment: Also please, reformat your code :)

Comment: This is a case where stepping through by hand or with a debugger would do you a world of good.

Comment: @Faibbus Thanks! It seems so obvious now.

Comment: @ Alan-Fey Not what it's suppose to do... It seemed like my question involved too much reading from those trying to help... I'll try to do better next time. Thanks!

Comment: @ pjs I tested the condition just by itself but I didn't see the mistake til now...Thanks!